# Vertical bar in bold

Tags: bold

I would like to create a vertical bar, as is, in a `\textbf{#1}` command:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Hello|there}

\texttt{Hello|there}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

How can I get the vertical bar working in bold-series?

EDIT:
I do not want to change the `|` char (I want to keep using `|`).

Comment: `\textbf{Hello\textbar there}`

Comment: @RunarTrollet please see the updated question, I would like _not_ to change the source code. :)

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487966/how-to-insert-pipe-symbol-in-tex#3488074